# why is default_head_blocks.xml not removing the css files?

Tags: magento, magento2

I have put 2 remove tags inside `default_head_blocks.xml`:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <remove src="css/print.css"/>
        <remove src="css/styles-m.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

The file is under `app/design/frontend/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/`

But the css files are not being removed. Should I put the file in a different directory?

Comment: I take it you've flushed the cache? Is the file actually under /<theme>/ or have you properly added the <Vendor> aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directory is correct. can you please try to flush cache and check again.